# How to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n+k}{n^3+k}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> How to evaluate the following limit?
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n+k}{n^3+k}$$

I think that every term of the sum is greater than the first one and smaller than the last one and then from the squeeze theorem the limit is $0$. However, I can't prove that inequality.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: The sum is less than $n \frac{n +n}{n^3+1}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n+k}{n^3+k}\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n+k}{n^3}\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n+n}{n^3}=\frac{2n^2}{n^3}=\frac{2}{n}\to0$$

Also, every term is $\geq 0$ so $0$ is also a lower bound.

Comment: Typo: $n + n = 2n$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Note that $n+1\le n+k\le 2n$ and $n^3+1\le n^3 +k\le n^3+n$.